# Как считать информацию из mpp файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project

Как считать текст, а именно название и содержимое полей из `mpp` файла?

С помощью этого не получилось вытащить содержимое полей.

```
import win32com.client

doc = 'file.mpp'
mpp = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSProject.Application")
```

Comment: Попробуйте библиотекой MPXJ. http://www.mpxj.org/

Comment: @Сергей с помощью этой библиотеки получилось получить все названия задач, а как остальное (кастомные поля прочесть) не понятно, но спасибо.